# Microsoft Teams : REST APIs

Tags: rest, api, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm interested in getting data (metadata and content of files) out of Microsoft Teams into my application using REST APIs. I have looked at Office 365 APIs and Graph APIs but, I could not find supporting documentation for Microsoft Teams.

Answer (score 21):

Teams API is now added to beta endpoint in Microsoft Graph. In documentation, you can find it together with Groups. Post, Channel and Chat Thread are available. 
For example, documentation for "channel" resource is here:
 https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/channel

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft Teams REST API is now included into MS Graph API

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/team?view=graph-rest-1.0

At the time of writing this answer there are not too many APIs around Teams. However more are being added and they are in **Beta** (sending messages, adding apps to team, uploading team image, and more).

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/team?view=graph-rest-beta

**It is not recommended to use Beta APIs in production environment as they might change.**

It is also worth of mentioning that Teams are actually Office365 Groups.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at Graph API

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/team?view=graph-rest-1.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/team?view=graph-rest-beta

Expand "Teamwork" at left side, you can get all Teams related API

Answer (score 2):

We do not have Teams APIs available at this time.  Our extensibility options are limited to experiences within the Teams application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I wish to fetch JSON objects such as team,team members,channels, and chats from Teams using REST API/Java SDK. Although I understand that Teams is not currently supported by APIs for Graph/Office 365, would it still be possible to achieve this using Sharepoint APIs or by any other means? I'd appreciate if you could point me to references. Thank you!

Comment: No not currently.  Bots in Teams support pulling a subset of those, but scoped specifically to that bot in the team in which it has been added.  To be clear, the user and channel information returned is suitable only for bot functionality.

Comment: @RichMoe-Microsoft with considerations with HIPAA compliance, it looks like every API integration point that currently exists explicitly forbids connectivity. Is it planned for Teams have a full-duplex REST api for organizations that cannot use bots?

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Graph API is constantly changing and we're currently using the following to monitor/interact with our Microsoft Teams application:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview

It gives access to the following (at the time of writing this):
[image]

We also monitor the general usage via the reports section in the Graph API:

[image]

This gives access to:

Device Usage:

1. Get details about Microsoft Teams device usage by user.
2. Get the number of daily unique users by device type.
3. Get the number of unique users by device type over the selected time period.

User Usage:

1. Get details about Microsoft Teams user activity by user.
2. Get the number of Microsoft Teams activities by activity type. The activities are performed by Microsoft Teams licensed users.
3. Get the number of users by activity type. The activity types are number of teams chat messages, private chat messages, calls, or meetings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/microsoft-teams-device-usage-reports?view=graph-rest-1.0